# How to index csv files using dih in solr

Tags: csv, indexing, solr, mapping, dih

I am new to solr so I might have wrongly written the dih.I have data already in my solr db and I need to extend my dih file such that it can index csv file which contain more information and csv and solr db data are mapped by common id.What I have done is -find in the code below

This is my csv file-->

```
Node_IP            probe_name      Global_ID    
10.53.3.87         ILRNAPSUD03     4b44aaff1e09f3d793fe9    
10.224.47.26       ILRNAPSUD03     47eebea2c2d485b59
```

Here is a dih snippet-->

```
<entity name="tmin"
 processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
 dataSource="FileDataSource"
 stream="true"
 url="${pickupdir.fileAbsolutePath}"
 onError="skip"
 forEach="/execution/" 
 transformer="script:makePair,script:makeLogPair, TemplateTransformer, 
 RegexTransformer, HTMLStripTransformer" 
>
<field column="jobid_t"  xpath="/execution/@jobId" />
<field column="destinationid_t"  xpath="/execution/@destinationid" />
<field column="id"  template="${tmin.destinationid_t}"  />
<field column="log_param"  xpath="/execution/log/@severity"  />
<field column="log"  xpath="/execution/log" />

<entity name="importcsv"
 processor="LineEntityProcessor"
 url="C:\Users\arpiagar\Desktop\IP Probe name_ILRNAPSUD01.csv"
 rootEntity="false"
 dataSource="FileDataSource" 
 header="true"
 separator="," 
 transformer="TemplateTransformer, RegexTransformer,script:mapcsv"  
>
<field column="rawLine"  groupNames="Node_IP,probe_name,Global_ID"/>
<field column="id"  name="Global_ID"  />
<field column="probe_name" name="probe_name" />

</entity>
</entity>
```

I need to map id in the tmin entity with the id which we will get after indexing csv data and index probe_name and node_ip at that particular id.

Comment: So what does `script:mapcsv` reference? Why do you have multiple transformers that you are not using? Is `Global_ID == tmin.id`?

Comment: I see `separator="," ` ... but I don't see any `,` in your "csv file" which looks more like tab separated values, or columnar data?